# How to reduce the spacing further more in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have a Word file with me which is done by some other guy.
[image]

This is the first page and I want to reduce the space between the first 3 lines. I set Line Spacing to 1 and Paragraph Spacing(both Before and After) to 0. But the spacing remains the same and it is not getting reduced any further than this.

I also have some other Word files in which I can reduce the spacing to minimum by setting Line Spacing to 1 and Paragraph Spacing(both Before and After) to 0. So I think this Word file has some property enabled or disabled in it which is not in the others. I don't know which is it.

How can I reduce the spacing ?

This is the file with formatting symbols.
[image]

One thing I noted is that the cursor has same size on the 3 lines. In the second figure you can see the size of the cursor. Actually the size of the fonts in 2nd and 3rd lines is 12 and in line 1, it is 16.

Comment: could you please post the same picture with visible formatting symbols?

Comment: @MátéJuhász Ok. But tell me how to enable formatting symbols ?

Comment: press CTRL+SHIFT+8

Comment: seems strange, are you sure spacing is correctly set for all the three paragraphs?

Comment: @MátéJuhász Yes. Am sure

Comment: "the cursor has same size on the 3 lines" that could be the reason, text size is 12 for what you see, but there can be some non-visible characters having bigger size, select the whole lines and set the font size again.

Comment: The paragraph marker at the end of the line has size 16. Select this and make it 12.

Comment: @DavidPostill How to select the paragraph marker ?

Comment: @TominJacob Select the characters either side - that will also select the marker. Make them all 12.

Comment: @DavidPostill I selected the characters as you said. Their size is showing 12 only.

Comment: @TominJacob Change them to 16 and back to 12

Comment: @DavidPostill I changed font. Amazingly I got what I need. The problem is with this specific font only.

Comment: @TominJacob Try changing the font back again. Which font causes the problem? Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill The font is Adobe Gothic Std B

Comment: @TominJacob And did changing it to another font and then back to Adobe Gothic Std B fix the problem?

Comment: @DavidPostill No

Comment: @TominJacob OK, then it's a broken font. Answer your own question ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill Also Narkisim font shows the same problem. How do I answer my question? I mean, what to say as an answer.

Comment: @TominJacob Just say that the problem was resolved by changing the font. And list the fonts that are causing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

After receiving help from a member of this community, I came to know that it was a font problem(broken font). I solved the issue by trying another font. I found two fonts are having this issue:

1. Narkisim
2. Adobe Gothic Std B